# how to add a button in web part?(entry level)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I created a web part on server side and deployed it successfully, but after I inserting that custom web part, no buttons shown up..

so my question is: How to creat a button with one method I've written already, and display on the web site automatically?

Can any body help a rookie?

Comment: Mn... lots of code I've pastest, can you tell me where to add a button? in usercontrol? or the webpart.cs file?

Answer (score 0):

Add all code to the usercontrol, use the webpart.cs file for code that relates to the webpart and loading the usercontrol (i.e. initialising usercontrol properties from webpart properties etc)

Answer (score 0):

If i have understood your question correctly than :

Your Custom webpart will have .ascx file and .ascx.cs file. Create a button in .ascx file and related method should come in ascx.cs

**.ascx**

```
<asp:Button ID="btnFacilities" runat="server" Text="Facilities" />
```

**.ascx.cs**

```
        protected void btnFacilities_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Your Code
        }
```

Deploy after adding and than check your site page.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know the difference between Visual Web Part (user control) and classic Web Part ?

If you mean add a button on visual webpart the code provided by Ishan is a good starting point.

If you mean classic wep part the code below will add a button on the web part :

```
public class YourWebPart : WebPart
{
    protected override void CreateChildControls()
    {
        Button YourButton = new Button();
        YourButton.Text = "Click me !";
        YourButton.OnClientClick = "alert('Cool stuff');";
        this.Controls.Add(YourButton);
    }
}
```